# TabItem fires FocusGot event when clicking on any control placed in it

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem, tabview

I'm getting a hit on the method below as soon as I click the tab in question.

```
private void Tab1_GotFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs) 
{
  DoStuff();
}
```

However, I noticed that when I click **any** control placed on that tab, the event is fired too. Can I turn off the behavior? Can I detect if the event is fired "for real" or "just for fun", so to speak?

A small voice in my head tells me to compare what's being gotten in focus with what's being lost and if it's the same (or childly) component, skip the method. But that sounds weird...

```
private void Tab1_GotFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  if(sender == eventArgs.OriginalSource)
    DoStuff();
}
```

Instead, I'm trying to work with the following.

```
private void TabControl_OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  ...
}
```

However, it's being fired and then re-fired due to something I do inside it. (I update the data grid contained on the one of the tabs upon the selection being changed. I suspect that sorting and/or filtering might cause those issues.)

Is this the right approach?

Comment: [`UIElement.GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) is bubbling event which means each `UIElement` within `TabItem` triggering `GotFocus` will eventually bubble up to `TabItem`. You can check which element trigged event by checking `e.OriginalSource`

Comment: So, the second part of the question, then? Is the other approach better (reacting to selection changed)?

Comment: It's the same thing with [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event. It's also bubbling event and if you try to handle it on `TabControl` be aware that it will also be triggered for each `Selector` control (like `ListBox`, `ComboBox`, `ListView`, `DataGrid`) within tab

Comment: That's unexpected... Well, is the middle part a correct way to handle the recognition? Or is there a smarter way?

Comment: Why do you need to handle `SelectionChanged` or `GotFocus` event? You should still be able to handle `SelectionChanged` event like that just ignore every call where `e.OriginalSource` is not `TabControl`

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Got confused, somehow. Put yours as a reply, mate, so I can accept it as an answer. Include both the method handling the event **and** the check for the item firing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments both [`UIElement.GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Selector.SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) are [bubbling events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx#routing_strategies) which means that they will bubble up the visual tree and event handler will be triggered on a parent control for every child that raises this routed event. In case of `GotFocus` event it will be every `UIElement` and `SelectionChanged` will be triggered by every [`Selector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector(v=vs.110).aspx) control like `ComboBox`, `ListBox`, `ListView` or `DataGrid`.

You should still be able to handle `SelectionChanged` event like that just ignore every call where `e.OriginalSource` is not `TabControl`

```
private void TabControl_OnSelectionChanged(
  Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  var tabControl = eventArgs.OriginalSource as TabControl;
  if (tabControl != null)
    SolveAllProblems();
}
```

It's not fool proof and if you will have `TabControl` as child of `TabControl` it will still be triggered. In case it's only supposed to handle a specific tab, the following will do just fine.

```
private void TabControl_OnSelectionChanged(
  Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  if ((eventArgs.OriginalSource as TabControl)?.SelectedItem == TabToBeHandled)
    SolveAllProblems();
}
```

Note the cool new addition to .NET - the surprised dot (coalescent operator).

Comment: I took the liberty to adding a section to cover the caveat. Hope it's OK. Also, do we really need to *as* the original source?